# "In" vs "on" and "below" vs "under"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which prepositions should I use here ?

> Working hours duration time should be below/under the one defined in/on parameter *default.time*.

Here the context was about programming languages parameters.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean the _position_ of another variable or the _value_?

Comment: The value of *default.time* parameter.

Comment: Then you definitely want 'less'. To describe relation in value use 'less/more', 'smaller than/ greater than'. To describe relation in position use 'underneath/above'.

Comment: @Nieszka: Very good point. I would prefer "below" over "underneath".

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: Ah, very true, for a minute there I forgot we were talking about documentation, not an essay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of language, I would go for:

> Working hours duration time should be *below* that defined *by* parameter default.time.

If you do mean the value (please see my comment on your question), then you need

> Working hours should be *less* than those defined *by* parameter default.time.

Comment: Ho Nieszka, why did you use "comment on your question" instead of "comment in your questions" ?

Comment: You comment *on* something or make a comment *about* something. You can also think of it as my comment wasn't actually inside your question.

Comment: @utxeee: "comment in question" means that the comment is part of the question. "Comment on question" means that a comment about the question.

Comment: +1 purely for paraphrasing to get rid of the word "duration", which in OP's construction serves no purpose other than to assert that the writer isn't a native English speaker (and possibly to annoy a few people who *are*! :)

Comment: +1 "less than" was the first thing that came to my mind.  Perfect for programmers (`<`!)

Answer (score 4):

There are many possibilities, including ones you haven't asked about. When I document software I've written, I like to use as few simple words as possible.

> Working hours duration time should be less than the value of the parameter `default.time`.

I'm a little concerned about "working hours duration time". I suspect that "time" is not needed, and an apostrophe is:

> Working hours' duration should be...

Comment: I would go even further and get rid of the 'duration'.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the unnecessary usage of "time"; duration is time in itself. Using "below" seems fine to me

Comment: @Nieszka "Working hours" is sufficiently ambiguous to require "duration" as well. My working hours (in British English) are 9-5 or thereabouts; to unambiguously get "8 hours" you need to call it "working hours' duration".

Comment: Probably there is a typo in the fragment "When I document software I've written."

Comment: @AndrewLeach: yes, I see your point. What would you say about 'work hours' then? Or 'work time'?

Comment: @Carlo_R. "Document" is a [verb](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/document?region=uk&q=document) meaning "write documentation"; that clause has the same construction as "When I play music I've written".

Comment: @Nieszka: "Work hours" means the same as "Working hours"; "Work time" *might* do, but my sentence also serves to define what the parameter `default.time` is used for. If you didn't explicitly say it was a duration, it's not really specific enough. Note also that *Working hours duration* (or whatever) should probably match what's shown on the screen in the application.

Answer (score 2):

Use "below" and "of parameter".

There is no need to say "....duration time....", duration is time. "Duration of working hours should be..." is sufficient ("working hours duration" sounds awkward).

As a programmer, I prefer using symbolic representations: "working hours must be < [default.time]" but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

> Working hours duration time should be below that defined in parameter default.time.

You could use under, but the context indicates below to mean lower, rather than under, which has connotations of physically being underneath.

A definition is in a parameter, not on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but why have you changed one to that ?

Comment: because you have already used duration time, so you don't then need to say 'the one that is defined', which is what your sentence means - instead you can just say 'that defined'

Comment: Rory, I'm not able to upvote yet but if I was certainly you would have got it :D

Comment: no worries - you can accept answers. See this for guidance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/154443

Comment: @Rory: It is incorrect to start a sentence with "and".

Comment: correct - and fixed :-)